# How to pass values in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In my workbook I have seven sheets. Sheets four through seven contain values of product information for our four production lines.

The below code starts on sheet 4 and loops through each row of column B until it finds the value of the combobox located on the userform named Chattem or Chattemfrm.cmbPrdCde.Value. It then will select that cell containing that value and offset to obtain the new cells value and assign that value to the corresponding variable of either txtDz, txtCs, and txtUOM. These variables are needed for a formula located in on the Chattemfrm. Once the user clicks on the command button labeled Print or cmdPrint the formula is calculated. The txtbxdz.value comes from the Chattemfrm Userform.

An excerpt of the formula.

> textValUp = ((txtbxdz.Value) / txtDz / txtCs) + 0.5 - 1E-16

How do I pass the value of those integers inside my sub to the above formula located on Chattemfrm?

I thought about declaring those variables as Public but I'm getting

> Run-time error '11': Division by Zero.

All declared variables have values associated with them. Perhaps there might be a better way?

```
Option Explicit
Public txtDz As Integer, txtCs As Integer
Public txtUOM As String
Sub Test()

Dim ws_count As Integer, i As Integer, FinalRow As Integer, x As Integer

ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For i = 4 To ws_count
    Worksheets(i).Activate
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 1 To FinalRow
        If Cells(x, 2) & " " & "(" & Cells(x, 3) & ")" = Chattemfrm.cmbPrdCde.Value Then
            Cells(x, 2).Select
            txtDz = Cells(x, 2).Offset(0, 2).Value
            txtCs = Cells(x, 2).Offset(0, 3).Value
            txtUOM = Cells(x, 2).Offset(0, 4).Value
        End If
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: if you tried public and still got a division by zero error then the problem isn't scope, there's something else going on.  use f8 to step through your code while probing your variables with the debugging/instant window. locals and watch windows are also helpful.  to address your question, forms can have properties just like classes.  you can  property let/get/set on the form.  you can also use tags.  depending on where you have your code you may be able to pass variables as parameters(not in predefined event procedures) ... in some cases you may have to move code outside of a control to pass

Comment: I'm still kinda new to VBA but could you provide an example that you feel might work. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use the offset cell values?

Comment: @jman good observation.  that would work until the variables change value - which doesn't appear to happen

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a local integer variable "MyValue" that a subroutine in a standard module wants to send to the userform.

Depending on the location of your code you may be able to get away with a parameter. If you want to use it in a standard procedure/function on the userform.

In the userform

```
sub UserFormProcedureName(byref ProcValue as integer)
```

from the module holding MyValue

```
call Chattemfrm.UserFormProcedureName(MyValue)
```

But if your code is in a control procedure, like

```
Private sub Combobox1_KeyUp( KeyCode
```

then you can't use a parameter and you'll either have to move your code or use a different method.

You could use `Tag` this is probably the easiest way other than using a worksheet or global.  Most objects have Tags.  Combobox, ListBox, UserForm etc. I tend not to use tags so I don't remember if all three of those have them but you can find it using the property window that's normally below the project explorer.

From the module with MyValue

```
Chattemfrm.ComboBox1.Tag = MyValue
```

in the UserForm

```
if me.ComboBox1.Tag = OneMillionDollHairs Then
    do something
End If
```

Another way would be to use class properties. A userform is essentially the same thing as a class module but with more capabilities.

First we need to decide how we want to use the variable and if we need to allow other procedures to use it. Let's assume you want to make it accessible to other procedures.  So immediately we know you'll be using Get and Let.

MyValue is a horrible name for a property because the variable belongs to a module so we'll name the property after the procedure e variable  belongs to "ProcValue" ... for procedure variable.

Now we need 1 more name before we can start, I'll add the prefix "i" to "ProcValue" and leave it at that. Anytime you want to use MyValue in the userform, you can use iProcValue or with a few exceptions me.ProcValue

now in the declarations of the code for your userform declare iProcValue as a private module integer.

then create the let ProcValue property to assign the variable and create the get ProcValue property to allow other procedures to see the variable.

It will look something like this

```
Option Explicit

Private iProcValue as integer

property let ProcValue(incomingValue as integer)
iProcValue = incomingValue
end property

property get ProcValue() as integer
ProcValue = iProcValue
end property
```

now in your subroutine that has MyValue you'd assign the value with

```
Chattemfrm.ProcValue = MyValue
```

if another module wants to use the value they could assign a variable

```
SomwOtherInteger = Chattemfrm.ProcValue
```

or use the property directly

```
If Chattemfrm.ProcValue > SomeLargeMumber Then
    'do somethung
End if
```

That should get you going.

Comment: Ok... I found out where the code error occurs but I still don't know why?

Comment: Ok... I found out where the code error occurs but I still don't know why? For some reason it won't offset.'code'
            If Cells(x, 2) & " " & "(" & Cells(x, 3) & ")" = Chattemfrm.cmbPrdCde.Value Then
                'Cells(x, 2).Select
                txtDz = Cells(x, 2).Offset(0, 2).Value
                txtCs = Cells(x, 2).Offset(0, 3).Value
                txtUOM = Cells(x, 2).Offset(0, 4).Value
             Cells(x, 2).Select
        Next x
    Next i
End Sub'code'

Comment: what happened when you add `value'?  If Cells(x, 2).value & " " & "(" & Cells(x, 3).value & ")" = Chattemfrm......  might want to select that line, press f9, then run your macro. when it stops, use the immediate window to test that statement and make sure it evaluates to what you expect

Comment: Ok... that worked within the Sub. It still didn't pass the value to the formula. Would declaring the same variables in cmdbtnPrint_Click() effect the passing of the value. Thank You.

Comment: YES!!! Apparently when declaring the same variables within the cmdbtnPrint_Click() DOES EFFECT the passing of the value. Thank You so very much for your help and guidance.

Comment: NO...Thank you again for your help. Now all I have to do is add some error traps, which I am sure I'll need help with, and tidy up some loose ends as far as my code is concerned, and I'll be done with my project.